# Run-Time check failure #2 Stack around the variable 'optionAddress' was corrupted

Tags: c

I've been getting this error AFTER my program is done running, but before I get the 'Press any key to continue...' prompt. Here is my code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

#include "contacts.h"
int main (void)
{
    // Declare variables here:

    struct Name names;
    char optionName;
    struct Address addresses;
    char optionAddress;
    struct Numbers number;
    char optionCell;
    char optionHome;
    char optionBusiness;

    // Display the title

    printf("Contact Management System\n");
    printf("-------------------------\n");

    // Contact Name Input:

    printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
    scanf ("%s", &names.firstName);
    printf("Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &optionName);
    while (optionName ==  'y' || optionName == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's middle initial(s): ");
        scanf("%s", &names.middleInitial);
        break;
    }
    printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
    scanf("%s", &names.lastName);

    // Contact Address Input:

    printf("Please enter the contact's street number: ");
    scanf("%s", &addresses.streetNumber);
    printf("Please enter the contact's street name: ");
    scanf("%s", &addresses.street);
    printf("Do you want to enter an apartment number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &optionAddress);
    while (optionAddress == 'y' || optionAddress == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
        scanf("%s", &addresses.apartmentNumber);
        break;
    }
    printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
    scanf("%s", &addresses.postalCode);
    printf("Please enter the contact's city: ");
    scanf("%s", &addresses.city);

    // Contact Numbers Input:

    printf("Do you want to enter a cell phone number? (y or no): ");
    scanf("%s", &optionCell);
    while (optionCell == 'y' || optionCell == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", number.cell);
        break;
    }
    printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &optionHome);
    while (optionHome == 'y' || optionHome == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", &number.home);
        break;
    }
    printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &optionBusiness);
    while (optionBusiness == 'y' || optionBusiness == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", number.business);
        break;
    }
```

I've looked through here to see how other people have fixed this issue but it seems like it's a memory issue or something and different for everyone. If I expand my program the error will not come until the code is finished. I've tried it without the "%s" and with " %c" instead, but when I do that the program skips the scanf's. If I've not provided enough information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried it without the "%s" and with " %c" instead, but when I do that the program skips the scanf's.

The reason behind stack corruption when you use %s is due to the null character (\0) which would be inserted after the single character. Since the size you have allocated for optionAddress is just a single character, you would be using more (at least two characters) than what you have allocated.

Therefore, using %c would be the right choice, and the skipping of scanfs would be probably due to the remaining newline characters in the input buffer. I'm not really sure which code will be able to fix this (Since I do not know how many scanfs are being skipped), but using getchar() to just remove a character(which could be a newline) from the input buffer, or using fflush(stdin) could help clearing the input buffer.

Using fflush(stdin) is not good practice though ,and even may not work depending on your environment. Just using " %c" like you did should usually solve the newline issue, but if it doesn't you could play around with getchar() until the scanfs are not skipped anymore.